# Identify div through css

Tags: html, css

I have this HTML Code:

```
<div id="loggedin">
</div>
<div id="notloggedin">
</div>
<div>
</div>
```

I want two identify the last div which is not "loggedin" and "notloggedin". How will I do that through css?

Comment: [Here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_selectors.asp), and go to "The id selector". edit: let me post an answer, see if that helps you more.

Comment: do you mean, you want to identify the 3rd div in your HTML?

Comment: @Phani --> you got me right. How will I do that?

Comment: @Alyssa Gono: I wrote an answer....that should do the trick for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This uses CSS3's `:not()` selector. It will work for all DIV that do not have an id attribute present.

```css
div:not([id]){
  color:green;
}
```

```html
<div id="loggedin">
  text
 </div>

<div id="notLoggedIn">
  text
</div>

<div>
  this should come out green
  </div>
```

### Another Example that came up as a result of comments

Since we are unaware of what your HTML looks like, this may be a bit better suited for your needs.

```css
.container > div:not([id]) {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="loggedin">
    Logged In
  </div>
  <div id="notloggedin">
    Logged Out
  </div>
  <div>
    This text should be green
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  this text should not be green because it isn't a child of the container div.
</div>
```

Comment: Very true, he could also limit the div search to the direct parent class/id of the wrapper (assuming there is one) or the body, e.g. `.container > div:not([id])` or `body > div:not([id])`

Answer (score 0):

Try to be a bit more clear in your question, to revise my answer, if you want to refer to the 3rd div (that's not what you asked at all). then as the others said, you need to wrap the three div's in a parent-div and refer to it using either nth-child, or [not]. You also asked this same question (worded differently) like 2 minutes before asking this one.

nth-child

```
div:nth-child(3) {

}
```

not

```
div:not([id]){

}
```

PS. I don't see any reason why you can't give the last div an id or class anyways.

Answer (score 0):

You can target the last `div` with CSS using three ways.

First way:

```
div:last-child {
    //styles come here
}
```

Second way:

```
div:nth-child(3) {
    //styles come here
}
```

Third way:

```
div:not([id]){
    //styles come here
}
```

There might be other ways as well using psuedo-selectors.

Answer (score 0):

use `:last-child` in your css for the div tag.

HTML:

CSS:

```
div:last-child
{
     //your styles for last div here.
}
```